# How can light travelling forward send an electron forward?

Tags: electrons, scattering

Light travels along the x-axis and strikes a stationary free electron.  Its E field oscillates along the y-axis.  The electron moves off at an angle with respect to the x-axis less than 90 degrees.  By what mechanism does light cause this electron to have a component of motion along the x-axis?

Comment: Don't forget that light also has a magnetic field.